# Add unique object into array reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i have problem here, when i click into one element 2 times it will add 2 time into my array, i dont know how to add unique element into array, can u guys help me? Thank you guys

```
 const handleClick = (
    id: number,
    name: string | null,
    avatar: string | null
  ) => {
    setListChoose((prevState: any) =>
      [...prevState].concat({ id, name, avatar })
    );
  };
```

[image]

Comment: Use an obejct instead of an array. Use the `id` as the key.

Comment: Is your `id` supposed to be unique?

Comment: yes, id is unique

Comment: @super can i guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that whether that contact exists in array or not. If not then append in list else don't.

```js
const handleClick = (
    id: number,
    name: string | null,
    avatar: string | null
  ) => {
    let list = Array.from(listChoose); //assuming that list name is listChoose.
    if(list.find(l => l.id === id) === undefined){
       setListChoose((prevState: any) =>
          [...prevState].concat({ id, name, avatar })
       );
    }
  };
```